# Instance table not regenerated after updating ExDate column in android CalendarProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, icalendar, android-calendar

I am working with a local calendar. Here is my code to create an event:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, 1457926200000L);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "P3600S");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2;WKST=SU");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 34);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EXDATE, "20160314T033000Z");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "R0");

Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Event is inserted correctly and while the `COUNT` is 2 in `RRULE`, I see just one event because of `ExDate`. But if I remove this line:

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EXDATE, "20160314T033000Z");
```

And update the inserted event:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EXDATE, "20160314T033000Z");
int update = getContentResolver().update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, 3612), values, null, null);
```

Event is updated  successfully (I query that and ExDate is updated correctly). However I see 2 events instead of one and it seems that `ExDate` is not working.

I know that it is possible to insert exception using `original_id` and `original_instance_time` and `CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI`. I want to know is there any other way to do that instead of inserting another event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART` to the `ContentValues` when you update the event (make sure you pass the original value).

As you can see in [CalendarInstancesHelper.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarInstancesHelper.java#627), the instances table update is skipped if `DTSTART` is not present in the modified `ContentValues`.

Comment: You are right. In addition to `DTSTART` I must include other related values (`RRULE` and `DURATION`). With these 4 values the result was OK. Thank you very much.